# Unable to fetch attributes from XML using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I am trying to extract the values of attributes from XML to JSON using XSLT.

XML

```
<root1>
    <root2>
        <test attr1="123" attr2="abc"/>
    </root2>
</root1>
```

JSON

```
 {
"attr1":"<xsl:value-of select="root1/root2/test/[@attr1"]/>"
"attr2":"<xsl:value-of select="root1/root2/test/[@attr2"]/>"
}
```

I tried many solutions but none of them are working. Headers and footer for XSLT is already taken care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing xsl you should adopt best practices and use templates for repeatative content. So in your example you should use a template to transform the attributes like so..

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root1/root2/test/@*"/>
     <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test="position()>1"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>":"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the xsl above I'm using a template that will a single attribute into a json name/value pair and the apply-templates is used to select all attributes from the root/root2.test node.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
"attr1":"<xsl:value-of select="root1/root2/test/@attr1"/>"
"attr2":"<xsl:value-of select="root1/root2/test/@attr2"/>"
}
```

You were using `[]` which defined a predicate (e.g. filters the node set), but what you want is just to get the attribute value.

Note that you will need to embed that into a foreach or separate template if your source XML has multiple XML elements from which you want to extract attributes; as-is this will take all attributes of all matching elements in the document.

Tested in [XSLT Fiddle](http://fiddle.frameless.io/) with the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />

  <xsl:template match="/">{
"attr1":"<xsl:value-of select="root1/root2/test/@attr1" />"
"attr2":"<xsl:value-of select="root1/root2/test/@attr2" />"
}</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is giving blank values

Comment: @ChetanPotdar Then you need to get your code straight. This works fine if the XSLT context is the document and the data is as provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

**<xsl:value-of select="root1/root2/test/[@attr1]"/>**
When we use [] predicates its returns Boolean value only  true or false you should write like:

**<xsl:value-of select="root1/root2/test/@attr1"/>**